# How to mock BigQuery insert?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, vitest

How can I mock BigQuery's insert?

It is a fluent interface, which make it dificult to mock.

I tried this:

```
vi.mock('@google-cloud/bigquery', () => {
  return {
    BigQuery: vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        dataset: vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
          return {
            table: vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
              return {
                insert: vi.fn(),
              }
            }),
          }
        }),
      }
    }),
  }
})
```

But I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'table')

On the line:

```
const table = dataset.table(BIGQUERY_ACTIVITIES_TABLE)
```

Comment: The complexity of that is exactly why you _don't_ mock it - don't mock things you don't own, put them behind facades you _can_ replace with test doubles and/or test them at the integration level.

Comment: I mocked successfully other APIs from AWS and Redis, why I cannot do the same for Google’s API?

Comment: I do not want to add layers to my application.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and adding `mockResolvedValue` to the `insert` method within the mock. If that method returns a promise, that would help simulate its asynchronous behavior

```js
vi.mock('@google-cloud/bigquery', () => {
  return {
    BigQuery: vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        dataset: vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
          return {
            table: vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
              return {
                insert: vi.fn().mockResolvedValue({ /* mock resolved value here */ }),
              };
            }),
          };
        }),
      };
    }),
  };
});
```

But the original error message you encountered (`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'table')`) suggests there was an issue accessing the `table` method or its return value.
So you still need to make sure that all parts of your mock return appropriate objects (or promises that resolve to objects). If any part of your mock chain incorrectly returns `undefined` or an unexpected value, it could lead to such errors when trying to access further properties or methods.

---

See if you can follow and adapt that [`PostHog/bigquery-plugin#main/index.test.ts`](https://github.com/PostHog/bigquery-plugin/blob/main/index.test.ts) example, using [jest](https://jestjs.io/):

```js
const mockedBigQueryTable = {
    insert: jest.fn(),
    getMetadata: jest.fn(() => [{ schema: { fields: []} }]),
    setMetadata: jest.fn(() => [])
}

const mockedDataset = {
    table: () => mockedBigQueryTable,
    createTable: jest.fn()
}

jest.mock('@google-cloud/bigquery', () => ({
    BigQuery: jest.fn(() => ({
        dataset: () => mockedDataset
    }))
}))
```

It does mock `insert` call, as shown in:

```js
test('makes the right call to bigQueryTable.insert', async () => {
    await exportEvents?.(
        [
            {
                event: 'test',
                properties: {},
                distinct_id: 'did1',
                team_id: 1,
                uuid: '37114ebb-7b13-4301-b849-0d0bd4d5c7e5',
                ip: '127.0.0.1',
                timestamp: '2022-08-18T15:42:32.597Z',
            },
            {
                event: 'test2',
                properties: {},
                distinct_id: 'did1',
                team_id: 1,
                uuid: '37114ebb-7b13-4301-b859-0d0bd4d5c7e5',
                ip: '127.0.0.1',
                timestamp: '2022-08-18T15:42:32.597Z',
                elements: [{ attr_id: 'haha' }],
            },
        ],
        meta as any
    )

    expect(meta.global.bigQueryTable.insert).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        [
            {
                json: {
                    bq_ingested_timestamp: expect.any(String),
                    distinct_id: 'did1',
                    elements: '[]',
                    event: 'test',
                    ip: '127.0.0.1',
                    properties: '{}',
                    set: '{}',
                    set_once: '{}',
                    site_url: '',
                    team_id: 1,
                    timestamp: '2022-08-18T15:42:32.597Z',
                    uuid: '37114ebb-7b13-4301-b849-0d0bd4d5c7e5',
                },
            },
            {
                json: {
                    bq_ingested_timestamp: expect.any(String),
                    distinct_id: 'did1',
                    elements: '[]',
                    event: 'test2',
                    ip: '127.0.0.1',
                    properties: '{}',
                    set: '{}',
                    set_once: '{}',
                    site_url: '',
                    team_id: 1,
                    timestamp: '2022-08-18T15:42:32.597Z',
                    uuid: '37114ebb-7b13-4301-b859-0d0bd4d5c7e5',
                },
            },
        ],
        {
            createInsertId: false,
            partialRetries: 0,
            raw: true,
        }
    )
}),
```

Comment: @Rodrigo No problem. Let me know if you manage to make it work.